# Can I use my AU flair for emails?

Tags: discussion, email, flair

I am trying to attach the code given for my AskUbuntu flair or the other one, the combined Stack Exchange flair, at the end of my emails just for show-off but it doesn't work. My recipients get the code but no image, anything at all to resemble the fancy images shown on askubuntu.com/users/flair page.

I am sure I am doing something wrong, and I am guessing that the given code for my flair cannot be used as an email signature, but if this is the case how can I show to my friends how big of a linux guru i am?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I knew there was something fishy with that code. But I did find a workaround, so to say ... I just attached the image to my emails, and it showed nice just bellow "my best regards/name" stuff. It is not a real signature but I can still show off my muscles :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Moved here from comment)

Most MUAs (mail reading programs) do not allow by default (for good reasons) the fetching of external images --- it would be a big privacy problem otherwise. The normal behavior should be the one you comment, and you have to actively load external images to see them.